# Android Application not recognizing a custom library with .aar file in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have Created an Android Library and I am trying to import it in my another android application using android studio 2.2 . I have added the library into my current project using .aar file with the help of [this official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency) , however, when I am trying to use it in my MainActivity class, my application is not recognizing that custom library.

This is how my MainActivityStaticLib class in looks like in library which implements different functions that I am trying to import:

```
package com.example.staticLib;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivityStaticLib extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_static_lib);
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is how app.gradle looks like in another android application

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "example.mystaticlibtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':my-custom-lib')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':my-custom-lib'
```

But in the following MainActivity page I am not able to import the library

```
package example.mystaticlibtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import my-custom-lib // It does not recognize 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing here to add. I looked into this, there are lot of answers I felt little vague or maybe little hard to follow for me. Please bare me, am newbie in android app development but learning. Any help on this would be highly appreciable

Thanks

Comment: Did you refresh grade build.

Comment: Yup I tried rebuilding it, no luck

Comment: Check you package name in the library. Is it my-custom-lib  ? In your example you are defining another package.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue when I was starting up with android, I solved it by changing the compileSdkVersion to 23 and targetSdkVersion to 21

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did tried changing versions but it's still not recognizing it

Comment: While importing, you have used the full package name right? You don't import the module name, you must import the appropriate classes, with their package names e.g.    import com.example.analyticslibrary.initialize.Activity

Comment: Okay gotcha,  I tried doing that as well but it is again not importing MainActivity class from my library when I am doing import package_name.* it dosent give me error but upon import package_name.MainActivity it gives me an error

Comment: You can't compile support libraries v24 with compileSdk = 23. Also it is not related to the question